# shared object in C# to be used in python script

Tags: c#, python, .net, share, shared-objects

I have created a windows app which runs a python script. I'm able to capture the output of the script in textbox.
Now i need to pass a shared object to python script as an argument from my app.
what type of shared object should i create so that python script can accept it and run it or in simple words how do i create shared object which can be used by python script.

thanks

Comment: I suggest you look into IronPython - http://ironpython.net/

Comment: @Daniel Kelley - i don't want to use IronPython.

Answer (score 1):

Since python is running as another process. This is no way for python to access object in c# directly since process isolation.

A way of marshal and un-marshal should be included to communicate between processes.

There are many way to communicate between processes. Share memory, file, TCP and so on.

Comment: using the Process approach.. i can run the python script from c#

Comment: @sia Process get only strings as prms, the OP asked about sharing objects

Answer (score 1):

5.4. Extending Embedded Python 
will help you to access the application object.
In this case both application and python running in single process.